# python pandas - update dataframe, replace values, add new rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, append

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020-06-15','2020-06-16','2020-06-17'], 'value':[1,2,3]})
 date       value
 2020-06-15 1
 2020-06-16 2
 2020-06-17 3

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020-06-17','2020-06-19','2020-06-18'], 'value':[40,100,70]})
 date       value
 2020-06-17 40
 2020-06-19 100
 2020-06-18 70
```

I would like to update and extend df1 with the new values from df2 to the following result. Just in case the indexes aren't in order, they should be sorted:

```
 date       value
 2020-06-15 1
 2020-06-16 2
 2020-06-17 40
 2020-06-18 70
 2020-06-19 100
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in one-line like so:

```
df = pd.concat([df1[~df1.date.isin(df2.date)], df2], ignore_index=True)
print(df)
#         date  value
#0  2020-06-15      1
#1  2020-06-16      2
#2  2020-06-17     40
#3  2020-06-18     50
#4  2020-06-19     60
```